# Find the derivative of $F(t) = \int_{0}^{\infty} \cos(t^2 h(x))e^{-x} \lambda(dx) \ \ (t \in \mathbb R)$ using derivative theorem.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $(X, \mathcal E, \mu)$ be a measure-space and $I \subseteq \mathbb R$ an open interval.

Let $f: X \times I \rightarrow \mathbb R$ be a function.

Consider $$F(t) = \int_X f^t(x) \mu(dx)=\int_X f(x,t) \mu(dx) \ \ (t \in I)$$

I've proven that $$F^{'}(t) = \int_X \frac {\partial} {\partial t} f(x,t) \mu(dx) \ \ (t \in I)$$

Now consider $h \in \mathcal M(\mathcal B(\mathbb R))$ with $\sup \{|h(x)| : x \in \mathbb R\} < \infty$.

I want to prove that $$F(t) = \int_{0}^{\infty} \cos(t^2 h(x))e^{-x} \lambda(dx) \ \ (t \in \mathbb R)$$ is well-defined and find an expression for the derivative $F^{'}(t)$.

I let $f: \mathbb R \times \mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R$ be given by $f(x,t) = \cos(t^2h(x))e^{-x}$.

It is easy to prove $f^t \in \mathcal L^1(\lambda)$. Also it is easy to prove that $f_x^{'}(t) = \frac {\partial} {\partial t} f(x,t)$ exist for all $t$.

Now all I need to prove is that there exist $g \in \bar {\mathcal M(\mathcal B (  \mathbb R))^+}$ such that $\int_{\mathbb R} g  \ d \lambda < \infty$ and $| \frac {\partial} {\partial t} f(x,t)| \le g(x)$ for all $(x, t) \in \mathbb R \times \mathbb R$.

However, I get $$ \frac {\partial} {\partial t} f(x,t) = -2th(x) \sin(t^2 h(x))$$ and no finite integrable function $g$ can exist, because I've the $t$ term in the partial derivative ? But, I need this function $g$ in order to apply derivative under the integral sign.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, it should read

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial t} f(x,t) = -2t h(x) \sin(t^2 h(x)) e^{-x}$$

(i.e. the "$e^{-x}$" is missing in your calculations).

Now recall that differentiability of a function is a *local* property. This means that $\mathbb{R} \ni t \mapsto F(t)$ is differentiable if, and only if, it is differentiable on intervals of the form $I_n := [-n,n]$ for each $n \in \mathbb{N}$. For $t \in I_n$, we have

$$\left| \frac{\partial}{\partial t} f(t,x) \right| \leq 2n \|h\|_{\infty} \cdot e^{-x}=:g(x).$$

Obviously, $g$ is integrable on $(0,\infty)$. Applying the derivative theorem, we obtain that $I_n \ni t \mapsto F(t)$ is differentiable and $$F'(t) = -2t \int_{0}^{\infty} h(x) \sin(t^2 h(x)) e^{-x} \, dx, \qquad t \in (-n,n).$$ Since this holds for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$, this finishes the proof.